# Objective-c runtime SIGSEGV on descrption

Tags: objective-c, runtime, core-foundation

I am playing with the objective-c runtime and getting a SIGSEGV when trying to print the description of an object:

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int
main()
{
  // SEL sAlloc = sel_registerName("alloc");
  SEL sInit = sel_registerName("init");
  SEL sDesc = sel_registerName("description");
  id desc; 
  Class nAuto = (Class)objc_getClass("NSAutoreleasePool");
  Class nObject = (Class)objc_getClass("NSObject");

  // Avoid __NSAutoreleaseNoPool warrning
  id nsAuto = class_createInstance(nAuto, 0);
  objc_msgSend(nsAuto, sInit);

  id ns = class_createInstance(nObject, 0);
  objc_msgSend(ns, sInit);

  desc = objc_msgSend(ns, sDesc);
  printf("%s\n", class_getName(ns->isa));
  printf("%s\n", class_getName(desc->isa)); // SIGSEGV triggered
  NSLog(desc);


  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So if anyone got an idea why this is happening. Thanks

Comment: somehow by looking at the assembly code near `objc_msgSend` there is an explanation. Just after the call there is a cltq instruction which sign extend the eax register to rax. So I am just wondering why `objc_msgSend` is declare to return a 32bit pointer?

Comment: By the way `NSLog(desc)` is a bad practice; use `NSLog(@"%@",desc)`. What happens if `desc` contains a stray `%@`? That will make your program crash. Although it doesn't seem to be the problem you're having here.

Comment: I founded. is due to the fact that objc_msgSend must be cast before use. It is written in the header objc/message.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objc_msgSend` must be cast before used:

```
desc = (IMP)objc_msgSend(ns, sDesc);
```